# Is there an efficient way in Pyspark to find an array's element that has the highest value but return another field?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I'd like to do something similar to `array_max()` but I need to return another field that's not being used to sort.

Here's the data that's in a column, let's call it `df.idInfo`:

```
[
    {
    "accountId": 123,
    "lastUpdated": {
        "sourceSystemTimestamp": "2023-01-01 07:44:58.000",
        "userId": null
        },
    "individualNumber": 33333
    },
    {
    "accountId": 456,
    "lastUpdated": {
        "sourceSystemTimestamp": "2023-02-12 18:44:58.000",
        "userId": null
        },
    "individualNumber": 22222
    },
    {
    "accountId": 789,
    "lastUpdated": {
        "sourceSystemTimestamp": "2023-03-23 23:44:58.000",
        "userId": null
        },
    "individualNumber": 11111
    }
]
```

I want to get the `individualNumber` from the element that has the latest value of `lastUpdated.sourceSystemTimestamp`.

Is there any efficient way to do this? Any built-in functions to Python or Pyspark I could leverage?

Comment: You can try `array_sort` and then take `individualNumber` from the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_max` to get the max value of `sourceSystemTimestamp` and use that to filter the same array to fetch the corresponding `individualNumber`.

```
df = (df.withColumn('max_time', 
                    F.array_max(
                        F.transform('idInfo', lambda x: x['lastUpdated']['sourceSystemTimestamp'])
                    ))
      .withColumn('max_number',
                  F.filter('idInfo', lambda x: x['lastUpdated']['sourceSystemTimestamp'] == F.col('max_time'))[0]['individualNumber']))
```